# Making a bash process is slow

Tags: java, bash

Below function takes a bash command, executes it, and returns the reply.

```
    public static String cmd(String s) {
        String out = "";
        try {
            Process pr = PB.command("bash","-c",s).start(); // PB is Process Builder
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            out = buf.readLine();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Shhh. be silent
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Command : `bash -c "java app <<< 5"` where *app.java* is an app that reads from stdin to do specific function.
This function takes approx. 617ms to execute, why is that? is there any performance optimization? 
**Edit : Problem was in *app.java*. However, It still takes ~12ms.**

Comment: May depend on the actual command you run. Can you please [edit] the question and make it a [mcve]? Also, do you need a new shell or can you do without calling `bash -c`?

Comment: @Robert I call 'bash -c'. Question is edited (with updates)

Comment: And do you need `bash -c`? What is `s`? [Mcve] please!

Answer (score -1):

Making a new process is slow on OS level. I am surprised it only took 600ms.
Multithreading came to existence exactly because creating new process is slow on OS level.

If you need something faster from java, stay in java and make an alternative implementation.

Comment: Well, It took ~12ms (question is updated). but its still slow.